# Angular $http status (-1)

Tags: angularjs, http, jetty

I call a backend service/resource by AngularJs `$HTTP GET`. When it is not available it returns `404` and Chrome Network tab shows that it is `404` as the followings:

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

BUT inside AngularJs `$HTTP` call result, I get `status=-1` and not `404`:

```
{data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: ""}
```

Why does it happen?

NB ) 
I have a jetty Service on the backend and enabled CORS:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "origin, content-type, accept, authorization"
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It returns -1 because, as the traces show, the GET request has not even been sent. What has been sent is the pre-flight OPTIONS request, which, by returning 404, prevented the browser to send the actual GET request.

Your server shouldn't return a 404 response for the OPTIONS request. It should return a 200 response.