# Handling expected and unexpected http request failures

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http-status-code-404

I am building an HTTP request <-> response link using AngularJS and PHP.

- On the server side there is a PHP service.
- On a client side there is a JS (AngularJS) service.

The code is working fine when I am just sending and receiving data. But now I want to handle situations when something goes wrong on the server. That is to say, I want to return status code from server that something went wrong or even a custom error message.

Here is the code which I am using to send data:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://' + remoteIP + ':1234/test/getCM2.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { test: 'abc'},
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    if (typeof data === 'object') {
        return data;
    } else {
        return $q.reject(data);
    }
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    return $q.reject(data);
});
```

The data is sent as an JSON object. On server side I handle the data:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata, true);
$test = $request['test'];

if (empty($test)) {
    // what to do here????
    // bad code ahead:
    http_response_code(401);
}

try {

    echo json_encode([
        "outData" => "def"
    ]);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // what to do here????
    // bad code ahead:
    $output = [
        'error'   => $e->getMessage()
    ];
    echo(json_encode($output));
}

?>
```

In PHP I am trying to set HTTP response status as following:

```
http_response_code(401);
```

It works flawlessly when I check the response in Chrome debugger:

[image]

But in AngularJS all I get is status = `-1`:

[image]

Usually when sending correct JSON request (without setting `http_response_code(401)`), there are 2 requests being made, first `OPTION` and then `POST`:

[image]

So, it seems like the `OPTION` request is taking my HTTP 401 error message at the beginning, but AngularJS never sees this error message because it is solely looking for the `POST` response. So the status which I see is `-1`, not `401`. `POST` wasn't even made.

I need to reply to clients with an error message, but I need an error which means something, not a `-1`. What would be the most appropriate way of handling such a situation?

I found [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483220/angular-http-status-1) related to `-1` status issue; unfortunately it doesn't help to solve the situation.

Comment: Print status from .error block

Comment: Options is the pre-flight check for allowing cross domain requests. Your API should intercept those and return 200 for valid host names, or return an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to only set headers and exit when the request method is OPTIONS.

Something like

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
     exit;
}
// only enter this part for POST
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

The CORS approach here might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/1175966