# AngularJs $http.post() send data null state:-1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Could anyone tell me why the following statement does not send the post data to the designated ***`URL`***?

```
login: function (username, password) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var url = Config.serverUrl() + "/api-token-auth/";
    var data = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    };

    $http.post(url, data).then(function (responseData) {
        console.log(responseData);
        alert(url);
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        $localForage.setItem('shopper-user', responseData.data).then(function (user) {

            var token = "JWT " + user.token;
            $rootScope.token = token;
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = $rootScope.token;

            deferred.resolve(user);
        });

    }, function (error) {
        alert(url);
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        console.error(error);
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

The URL is called on the server, but only go to the *error state*

#### Error:

```
{"data":null, "status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST"}}
```

Comment: what is your response code? 500?

Comment: Your server is not responding/request is timing out, try to [ping](https://iihelp.iinet.net.au/How_to_run_a_ping_test) the server and see what you get back

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular $http status (-1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483220/angular-http-status-1) (not adding the close vote yet, will wait for feedback from OP)

Comment: The most common cause of status -1 is a [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) violation. Modify the server to use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to allow cross-origin access.

Comment: Also there is no need to manufacture a promise with `$defer` as the `$http` service already returns a promise. See [Is this a “Deferred Antipattern”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side code seems OK.

It's probably a CORS issue. Pleasure ensure server-side code responds 200 to OPTIONS request (made by Angular before POST request) and that response headers are properly set.

You can find more information on how to configure CORS [here](https://enable-cors.org/)