# Ionic Native HTTP returning -1 status error on Ios Simulator

Tags: ios, angular, wordpress, ionic-framework, ionic-native-http

**[Ionic Native HTTP](https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http) returns {status: -1} for a single API call in IOS Simulator**

I'm using Ionic Native HTTP to get around CORS issues in IOS and there's a single Wordpress API call /wp-json/wp/v2/ that is always returning -1, despite the fact that other /wp-json/wp/v2/ api calls work perfectly fine.

In addition, this works fine in Android, it's just IOS that's having issues.

**HTTP Code** where http = @ionic-native/http/ngx

```
const url = https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/data?order=asc&order_by=id&per_page=100&after=2020-07-30 00:00:00&before=2020-07-30 23:59:59;

this.http.get(url, {}, {})
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('returning data');
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('erroring');
    console.log(err);

    console.log(err.status);
    console.log(err.error); // error message as string
    console.log(err.headers);
  });
```

There's nothing special about this code, it's just a single Wordpress API call, but I always get -1 returned. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483220/angular-http-status-1) states it's a CORS issues, where pre-flight OPTIONS requests get rejected, but the entire point of Native HTTP was to avoid CORS as I cannot modify the server.

Has anyone else encountered and fixed this status -1 issue?

**EDIT**
See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the space in the URL, it seems that Android and browsers automatically replace the space with %20, but IOS does not.

Thus the new URL should be as below and that now works fine.

```
const url = https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/data?order=asc&order_by=id&per_page=100&after=2020-07-30%2000:00:00&before=2020-07-30%2023:59:59;
```